# How do I programatically pop up a console from winMain in C?

Tags: c, console, winmain

```
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE p1, HINSTANCE p2, LPSTR p3, int p4)
{

}
```

I want a console to pop up when I click a button,what's the proper way to do it?

**UPDATE**
How do I output text to that console?

Comment: A console owned by your application?  Or a console window in a new process?

Comment: Owned by my application.

Answer (score 2):

Try using AllocConsole()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: How do I output text to that console?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
Write Console or just see Console Functions at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx